# How to read sequence of ".jpg" images in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am now currently trying BackgroundSubtractorMOG and BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 in OpenCV and I would like to try sequence of jpg images as the source of my frames

```
frame = imread("C:\images\001-capture.jpg");
    if(!frame.data){
    //error in opening the first image
    cerr << "Unable to open first image frame: " << fistFrameFilename << endl;
    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Also because I am getting error when I used the VideoCapture to access my .avi video clip.

```
VideoCapture capture("C:\movie1.avi");
if(!capture.isOpened()){
    //error in opening the video input
    cerr << "Unable to open video file: " << videoFilename << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//read input data. ESC or 'q' for quitting
while( (char)keyboard != 'q' && (char)keyboard != 27 ){
//read the current frame
if(!capture.read(frame)) {
  cerr << "Unable to read next frame." << endl;
  cerr << "Exiting..." << endl;
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- try VideoCapture capture("C:/movie1.avi"); // use either a single "/" or a double "\" !
- VideoCapture can read image sequqnces too, if they're correctly numbered:

  VideoCapture capture("C:/images/%3d-capture.jpg");  // btw, same slash probs as above

Answer (score 2):

The VideoCapture method stated by *@berak* is correct; though I inevitable have had issues while using it.. While reading sequential images, I always prefer the more direct approach as stated below. It gives you more control over the way you traverse your data while not limiting your speed.

```
char* Dataset_Dir( "C:/Data/" ); // Or take it from argv[1]
cv::Mat normal_matrix;
std::vector<cv::Mat>* image_stack;
for( int i=1; i<=endNumber; ++i )
{
    // Gives the entire stack of images for you to go through
    image_stack->push_back(cv::imread(std::format("%s/%03d-capture.png", Dataset, i), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)); 

    normal_matrix = cv::imread(std::format("%s/%03d-capture.png", Dataset, i), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this code `cv::VideoCapture cap("G:/var/cache/zoneminder/events/1/13/10/21/07/50/00/%3d-capture.jpg");` and it works. The image file though should have increasing number in its filename to be read in sequence.

Answer (score -1):

Steps:

1. store the path to file folders in a text file 
   /home/user/Desktop/Test/train.txt
2. My text file has entries :

   /home/user/Desktop/Test/001.ak47/001_
   /home/user/Desktop/Test/002.american-flag/002_
   /home/user/Desktop/Test/007.bat/007_
   /home/user/Desktop/Test/014.blimp/014_
   /home/user/Desktop/Test/022.buddha-101/022_
3. `sprintf(path,"%s%04d.jpg",name,i);` part of code does appending of file names. 
   My files are of the format `001_0001.jpg` for folder `001.ak47` and so on
4. The code reads 20 images from each folder and display it.

   ```
    int main ()
       {
              ifstream file("/home/user/Desktop/Test/train.txt");
              string temp;
              string string2;
              int count = 0; // number of folders
                  int number_of_folders = 5 ;
                  char name[70];
              char path[70];
              while(count != number_of_folders)
              {
                   getline(file, temp); // read first line of folder             //basically path to first folder
                   int i=1;
                   strcpy(name, temp.c_str());

                   while(1)
                 {

                   sprintf(path,"%s%04d.jpg",name,i);
                   Mat src= imread(path,1);

                    if(!src.data || src.rows == 0 ||  i == 21 ) break;        //use only 20 images for training
                   imshow("src",src);
                   i++;
                   waitKey();

                  }


                   count = count+1 ;
                   if(count == number_of_folders)
                       break;
              }
            file.close();
            return(0);
       }
   ```